# Codeigniter - setting up directories and files permissions (chmod settings)

Tags: php, codeigniter, permissions, chmod

Since i don't think i got right permissions all over my application folders and files is there anyway to check the right permissions allover them?

I mean, does anyone knows/has a standard/tutorial/link to follow for Codeigniter to set `chmod` permissions?

thanks, any help appriaciated!

**NB: when i say allover i mean from the root to all files the application & system folders contains**

Also to specify little bit, i think i got problems with permissions, cause i passed my application through different OS and for example macosx setted different permissions on directories than windows etc... so it's sort of a hell actually

This is my app schema:

```
/project
   /application
   /system
   /css
   /img
   /vendor
   index.php
   .htaccess
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to:

```
chmod -R 0644 application system index.php
```

Assuming that CI is installed in the web root, with the `application/` and `system/` directories residing therein, which is the default setup.

What I typically do is put the `application/` and `system/` directories *outside* of the web root when I use Codeigniter, at which point you need to edit your `index.php` file to reflect that:

```
$system_path = '../system';
$application_folder = '../application';
```

Note, you'd be adding the `../` (and also need to move those directories one level down) but I digress. The permissions for each *directory* should be 0755 and for each `.php` file 0644, wherever you end up putting them. This includes any vendor, 3rdparty, sparks, etc, and any custom asset locations.

If using a templating engine of some sort, *good* setups will work with 0755 folder permissions at the location where the engine writes its output and intermediate output if applicable. If you find that breaking, find a host that supports suexec so that you don't have to make those locations 777 (or world writeable).

This is most easily done using a terminal (SSH), but should also be easily possible with whatever file manager thingadongdong your host provides.

Answer (score 0):

change the permission of your codeigniter folder with this command:

```
$ sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/Codeigniter_folder_name
```